# Payload size for string and bytes

Tags: solidity

I have seen code on mitigate payload attack as such.
So from this code, i can assume that an address have a payload size of 32 not 20? What about other datatype like bytes, string, uint8 etc. Where can i find the payload size of each data type?

```
contract NonPayloadAttackableToken {
    modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) { 
          assert(msg.data.length >= size + 4);
      _;    
}
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {
     // do stuff   
}
```

Comment: Worth noting an example of this, in Gnosis MultiSigWallet test, at https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/TestToken.sol.

Comment: The documentation on this example states `This modifier is present in some real world token contracts, and due to a solidity bug it was not compatible with multisig wallets`. Not sure what it means though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal specification is the [solidity ABI](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/abi-spec.html#formal-specification-of-the-encoding)

- All static types are padded to 32 bytes, ie uintXXX, address, bool, etc.
- Dynamic types like string, bytes and arrays are encoded in two pieces, a "header" that has a fixed 32 bytes size and a "tail" that contains the data that has variable size.
- Tuples and structs, see documentation. Since a tuple can has static and dynamic types it is a mix of both.

---

Enforcing precise data size can be problematic in general.

For example multisig wallets (ie solidity call) will add data padding, for that reason the check is with greater or equal (`msg.data.length >= size + 4`).

It can cause problems if you want to use a function with that modifier from another public function.

```
function foo(uint a, uint b) 
    public 
    onlyPayloadSize(2*32)
{
    bar(a, b, msg.sender);
}

function bar(uint a, uint b, address c)
    public
    onlyPayloadSize(3*32)
{
    // If called directly it will succeed
    // If called from 'foo' it will fail. msg.data are foo parameters only
}
```

Some frameworks have removed those checks because it can cause lots of problems to try to maintain them.

Comment: So if my function is (bytes, string, uint) it will still be onlyPayloadSize (3*32) for the payload validation?

Comment: No, bytes and string are dynamic types, each will have 32 + data length.